# How to make the list of spinner items rounded? Not the spinner itself, but dropdown list

Tags: android, xml, spinner

I want to display the items of spinner in rounded rectangle list, not the default rectangle. I don't mean the spinner itself, but the list which falls after arrow is clicked. Is there a way to do this? The attempt to make custom_rounded_layout and attaching to it adapter changed the layout of each item, not the list itself. However, I want the list itself to be rounded, not the items. Right now the list is the default one. I want to make the corners of the list a bit rounded. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a layout file with a rounded background textview like this:

**spinner_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_40"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_round"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:id="@+id/ssdsd"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="@string/app_name" />
```

Now pass this in the spinner adapter

```
Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.yourSpinner);
spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String(this,R.layout.spinner_item,R.id.ssdsd,list));
```

To change the popup background, use this on your Spinner xml code:

```
        android:popupBackground="@drawable/bg_round"
```

**NB:**  You might need to adjust padding and margin to make it look good, this is just an idea of how you can do it.

Comment: Thanks, but it not working for the the list itself. After the item is chosen, item is shown in custom designed layout. But drop down list is still the same

Comment: Try replacing this line: 
`spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String(this,R.layout.spinner_item,R.id.ssdsd,list));`

With this: 
`spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String(this,R.layout.spinner_item,list));`

And see if it works or not

Comment: I tried it. The list is the default one as it was. The only change is when I select the item, item appears in custom textview after selection

Comment: Ok, have you used a rounded background in the textview? This line : 
`android:background="@drawable/bg_round"`

If yes, what is the background color of this drawable, if it is white or transparent, try changing the color to black or something

Comment: . The list is the same, but the items are affected.

Comment: I will try to attach a screenshot one minute

Comment: I attached it to the question itself. The list is the same, it is not changing. I made it red just for better visibility purposes

Comment: Rounded layout is being rendered by the items, not the list itself

Comment: Don't you want to display the items of the spinner in a rounded rectangle? Sorry, but I am not getting what you want.

Comment: I want the edges of the list itself to be rounded. The list which falls when arrow is clicked from spinner, that white background

Comment: Sorry, I was traveling. You can change the popup background by this line:
        `android:popupBackground="@drawable/bg_round"`

I also updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!